# Не могу установить соединение с базой данных MySQL с JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

JDBC.java

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class JDBC {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/currency";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "root";
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM rates");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(0));
                }
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

В pom.xml зависимость для JDBC установлена.

Вывод:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
        at by.bsu.pt.back.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:13)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2983)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
        ... 13 more
```

Ошибка в строке:

```
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Но при этом:
[image: соединение средствами Intellij Idea]

Answer (score 5):

Проблема была решена сменой версии драйвера в **pom.xml** на *8.0.11* и добавлением параметра **useSSL=false** в строку адреса

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/currency?useSSL=false";
```

Comment: `Class.forName()` не требуется для этой версии. И еще - юзайте `try-with-resources` или закрывайте все в блоке `finally` с проверками на `null` и прочим гемороем